# Output net view to XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, webforms

I am having trouble trying to get this to work.

What I am trying to achieve: use CMD to run a net view command and put the results into a XML file that looks something like this.

```
<Net_View>
    <result id=1>
        Andy's Computers.
    </result>
    <result id=2>
        Chris PC
    </result>
</Net_View>
```

Sorry for not posting more code!!

```
protected static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string output = string.Empty;
        string error = string.Empty;

        using (Process cmd = new Process())
        {
            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c Net View /all";

            cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            cmd.Start();

            while (!cmd.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadLine();

                if (line == "There are no entries in the list.")
                  return null;

                if (line != string.Empty)
                {
                    if (line[0] == "\\")
                }

            }

            using (StreamReader str = cmd.StandardOutput)
            {

            }

            using (StreamReader str = cmd.StandardOutput)
            {
                error = str.ReadToEnd();
            }


                string SANG = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();


            cmd.Close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: which error you got?

Comment: no errors as such yet as i havn't finished writing the code but it's not going well and outta frustration i deleted my solution. Just can't figure it out.

Comment: :-) ok I got.. well to be honest this's not the precise scope of StackOverFlow.. but I'll try to help you.. let me try a little what you already wrote...

Comment: thank you for taking pity on me =[ i dont normally struggle this much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resulting code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Xml;

namespace XMLNet
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Executing cmd... ");

            using (Process _cmd = new Process())
            {
                _cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                _cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c Net View /all";

                _cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                _cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                _cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

                _cmd.Start();

                using (XmlTextWriter _writer = new XmlTextWriter("net_view.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    int _id = 0;

                    _writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
                    _writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                    _writer.Indentation = 2;
                    _writer.WriteStartElement("Net_View");

                    while (!_cmd.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        string _line = _cmd.StandardOutput.ReadLine();

                        if (_line == "There are no entries in the list.")
                            return;

                        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_line))
                        {
                            if (_line.StartsWith(@"\\"))
                            {
                                string _aux = _line.TrimStart('\\').TrimEnd();

                                _writer.WriteStartElement("result");
                                _writer.WriteAttributeString("id", _id.ToString());
                                _writer.WriteString(_aux);
                                _writer.WriteEndElement();

                                _id++;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    _writer.WriteEndElement();
                    _writer.WriteEndDocument();
                    _writer.Close();
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        }
    }
}
```

It does exactly what you require.